# How do I automatically delete my old webhooks once I reach my webhook limits on Discord?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, webhooks

Information on webhooks is a bit scarce on the internet.
I have a bot that creates a webhook when a certain command is sent in the discord chat. These webhooks pile up pretty quickly and manually deleting them is really tedious. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try .delete(reason) method on the webhook.
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Webhook

You can also fetch all the webhooks with .fetchWebhooks() method.

Example:

```
guild.fetchWebhooks()
  .then(webhooks => console.log(`Fetched ${webhooks.size} webhooks`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchWebhooks

Using these two methods, you can delete webhooks automatically.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit new to webhooks, so could you elaborate a bit more? Thank you.